# NIFI Processor won't call the @OnStopped or @OnDisabled functions

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NIFI-Processor that subscribes to a few tags on a OPC UA server.
I'm struggling to find a way to terminate the subscription. My plan was to just keep it running until I decide to stop the processor.

I tried defining functions for @OnStopped, @OnUnscheduled and @OnDisabled, but they never get called when I stop or disable the processor.
I'm on NIFI 1.7 so I can terminate the processor's thread, but my @OnStopped, @OnUnscheduled and @OnDisabled functions still don't get called.

Does terminating the thread mean that the thread won't return from onTrigger in a fashion that allows calling the above mentioned lifecycle methods?

EDIT: As requested, my method with annotation:

```
@OnStopped
private void OnStopped() {
    getLogger().info("Subscriptions cleared - stopped");
    miloOpcUAService.clearSubscriptions();
}
```

Comment: How do you say "they aren't called"?

Comment: please provide you method declaration with desired annotation.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you're asking about how I know the methods aren't called, I use a debugger, which never enters the @OnStopped etc. methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method has to have public visibility, otherwise the scheduler (which uses reflection) can't find it to invoke it.